# Rails - how to get ID of currently updated records (with using "update_all")?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am updating some record, like this:

```
CarService.where("a = ? AND b = ?", a, b).update_all(color: color)
```

How do I get the IDs of records that has been updated from the query above?

```
updated = CarService.where("a = ? AND b = ?", a, b).update_all(color: color)
```

returns only `0`.

Thanks.

Comment: it returns the number of updated records, in this case, it's 0, so there are no records match your `where` condition

Comment: Yes, but I am looking to get a list of updated IDs, not only their numbers.

Comment: Do you want to know which records did NOT have that color before?

Comment: I want to know for which records was the color set/updated.

Comment: Let me ask differently: Should the list include records whose color was already the target color?

Answer (score 3):

`update_all` returns the number of records that were updated, so you can't get the ids "with using `update_all`", but you can get them from the same scope.

```
services = CarService.where("a = ? AND b = ?", a, b)
ids = services.pluck(:id) # efficiently grab just the ids
services.update_all(color: color) # reuse the scope to update the records
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, `update_all` returns the number of records that are updated.

For your situation, what comes to mind is to simply store the ids somewhere first.

```
car_services = CarService.where("a = ? AND b = ?", a, b) 
car_services.update_all(color: color)
updated_ids = care_services.map(&:id)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
services_to_change = CarService.where("a = ? AND b = ? AND color <> ?", a, b, color)
services_to_change.update_all(color: color)
ids_of_changed_services = services_to_change.pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will fail if your update changes the predicate in the `where` query, as the `update_all` only executes an `update table set x = y where predicates` and then the pluck will execute the original query, which no longer matches.

Comment: Point taken. However I'm surprised to get a downvote for this. Note that the question does not include that kind of constellation. Also, your issue has been addressed in the answer by @Carl Zulauf, how about granting him an upvote?